# Adding black borders to image without quality loss

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a 21:9 image with 1920x816 resolution, and i want to add black bars on top and bottom in order to comapre it with same one with 1920x1080 resolution . I tried 2 solutions for that, one using OpenCV and second using Image from Pillow. However, both of those reduced quality of images.

Not edited images are taken from video file using VapourSynth and FFMS2.

Comparison between files: (1920x816 frame.png and 1920x1080 frame.png are not edited files)

https://diff.pics/rKVbxTRRPG35

Am i missing some important options that will prevent quality loss? Or should i use different library for that?

Code that i used for OpenCV:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('1920x816 frame.png')
color = [0, 0, 0]
top, bottom, left, right = [132, 132, 0, 0]
img_with_border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=color)

cv2.imwrite("1920x1080 after OpenCV.png", img_with_border)
```

And for Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

old_im = Image.open("1920x816 frame.png")
new_im = ImageOps.expand(old_im, border=(0, 132))

new_im.save("1920x1080 after Pillow.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: PNG uses lossless compression, and you don't do any operations that would reduce quality. Why do you say you are losing quality? How can you tell?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there's a difference i quality. But there is a difference in Gamma value between the image files. Your original was saved with gamma 0.45455, and the processed image was saved with no gamma value.

Here's an explanation of what gamma means in png files: https://hsivonen.fi/png-gamma/

It's probably best to just strip the gamma value from both images. Pillow doesn't provide any simple way to work with the gamma metadata, and I'm not sure if openCV does either.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, i realized that i am an idiot. If i take frame with Vapoursynth, i might as well use it to add the needed border.

`video = core.std.AddBorders(clip = video, top = 132, bottom = 132, color = [0,0,0])`

That gets the job done without any additional compression. Maybe someone will make use of it.